# How to test browser performance of specific CSS property?

Tags: css, performance, testing

The website I work for has a lot of overly complex pages. If I was able to use box-sizing on them my job would be made significantly easier in a number of respects. However, before I can just roll up and use box-sizing I need to convince the powers that be that using it does not create a noticeable degradation in page performance.

Now, the page they care about the most is a whopping 2.5 MB of resources (images, HTML, CSS, JS, etc) and the .htc file I'd need to upload is around 4 kb. So 0.0016% of the total file size. No problem there.

However, while this won't add any real rendering overhead to all the modern browsers, it will to IE6 and IE7 due to their needing to reference this behavior file.

The issue is, how do I test the page performance difference caused by using this behavior file?

I tried the CSS Stress Test but after it tested the 500+ other rules already applied to the page it only displayed a scant few results and not one related to the one I actually wanted.

Ideas?

The stress test I used was:
andy.edinborough.org/CSS-Stress-Testing-and-Performance-Profiling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find a single IE+CSS performance tool to cover ie7/ie6.

What I can tell you from my experience using .htc files, namely csspie...is that you want to look at it from a js perspective, not css.

Having said that, to test js performance on ie6/ie7, try these:

- DYNATRACE: http://ajax.dynatrace.com/pages/
- COMPANION JS: http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/CompanionJS/HomePage
- FIREBUG LITE: http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite
- DEBUG BAR: http://www.debugbar.com/

I'm afraid I can't be more specific given there's no 'sample' live file to work with provided in your original post. Hope this helps.

Regards
G